# Microsoft SQL Server Login Stuck

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017-express

I have a Microsoft server 2012 running Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Express database. I am trying to log in through SQL Server Management on a remote machine but the log in loads forever and gives no error.

If I put in the wrong username and password I do get an error that the username and password is wrong and the error shows in the SQL Server log so it does seem to be making some type of connection.

When I connect on the local server it connects right away.

I have TCP enabled in the server configuration.

Does anyone know why this hang might be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only reason seems to be large database server with too many fragmented databases and may be slow network speed at the moment.